# Conditional rendering inside a template element used for looping over an array

Tags: vue.js, petite-vue

I have to conditionally render elements in a list using Petite-Vue. However, placing a `<li>` tag with a v-if attribute inside a `<template>` tag with a `v-for` attribute generates this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertBefore')

So this code, which is what I would need, doesn't work:

```
<ul>
      <template v-for="item in ['a', 'b', 'c']">
           <li v-if="['a', 'b'].includes(item)">{{ item }} is included in ['a', b'']<p></p></li>
           <li v-if="['a', 'b'].includes(item)"><hr/></li>
           <li v-if="item === 'c'"><p> item is c</p></li>
      </template>
</ul>
```

However, if the conditionally rendered elements are not placed in a `<template>`, but in, let's say, a `<div>` tag with a `v-for` attribute, it works. So this works:

```
<div>
      <template v-for="item in ['a', 'b', 'c']">
           <p v-if="['a', 'b'].includes(item)">{{ item }} is included in ['a', b'']</p>
           <hr v-if="['a', 'b'].includes(item)" />
           <p v-if="item === 'c'"> item is c</p>
      </template>
</div>
```

Is there any way to use Vue to conditionally render a variable number of `<li>` elements depending on the current iteration through an array or object?

Comment: I believe `v-for` and `v-if` need to be on an element other than  `<template>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking [at this](https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue/discussions/159), I guess it's a well-known issue but also part of the limitations of [petite-vue](https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue).

I suspect that it might just not support that feature at all but you can always write this

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/petite-vue" defer init></script>

<div>
  <ul v-for="item in ['a', 'b', 'c']">
      <li v-if="['a', 'b'].includes(item)">{{ item }} is included in ['a', b'']<p></p>
      </li>
      <li v-if="['a', 'b'].includes(item)">
        <hr />
      </li>
      <li v-if="item === 'c'">
        <p> item is c</p>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Adds the benefit of not creating an empty `ul` if there is nothing to loop on.